# Is there a way to force a function or method to be called using named parameters only?

Tags: php, function, methods, named-parameters

For example, let's say we wrote the following function:

```
function myFunction(
    Foo $foo,
    Bar $bar,
) {}
```

In the future, we realize we want to re-order our parameters:

```
function myFunction(
    Bar $bar,
    Foo $foo,
) {}
```

If this function is only ever called using named parameters, then the above change does not break any existing code.

Therefore, is there a way to force a function or method to be called using named parameters only?

Comment: Not afaik, but read here: https://php.watch/versions/8.0/named-parameters

Comment: If you would require call it only via named parameters, then what's holding you from just switching parameters order in these calls. In both cases you will have to change code

Comment: You can leave this function header and just call internally another method with proper params order

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to, then one way would be to use an array parameter

```php
function myFunction ($par)
{ 
  $Foo = $par['Foo'];
  $Bar - $par['Bar'];
}
```

call it

```php
$param = ['Foo'=>23.4, 'Bar'=>'Hello'];
myFunction ($param);
```